# Guardar datos de broker MQTT en una base de datos SQlite instalada en RaspberryPi

Tags: python, sql, raspberry-pi, mqtt

Estoy monitorizando el consumo eléctrico de una prensa de gran tamaño. Lo hago con un Energy Meter de Circuit Setup (que incluye un ESP32 y un ATM90E32) muestreando cada 50ms. Estoy enviando datos a través de MQTT a una Raspberry Pi, pero ahora tengo que almacenar esos datos para su posterior análisis. Estoy leyendo los datos perfectamente en el suscriptor (Raspberry) pero no sé cómo almacenarlos correctamente.

El script que he desarrollado en Python es el siguiente (es la primera vez que trabajo tanto con Python como con SQL así que si veis alguna barbaridad, no os riais mucho :P)

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sqlite3
from time import time
 
MQTT_HOST = '192.168.0.xxx'
MQTT_PORT = 1883
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = 'Python MQTT client'
MQTT_USER = 'xxxx'
MQTT_PASSWORD = 'xxxx'
TOPIC = 'home/energy/sensor'
 
DATABASE_FILE = 'mqtt.db'
 
 
def on_connect(mqtt_client, user_data, flags, conn_result):
    mqtt_client.subscribe(TOPIC)
 
 
def on_message(mqtt_client, user_data, message):
    payload = message.payload.decode('utf-8')
 
    db_conn = user_data['db_conn']
    sql = 'INSERT INTO datos_electricos (topic, tension, intensidad, potencia, factor, fecha) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, (message.topic, datos, int(time())))
    db_conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
 
 
def main():
    db_conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE)
    sql = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datos_electricos (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        tension FLOAT,
        intensidad FLOAT,
        potencia FLOAT,
        factor FLOAT,
        fecha TIMESTAMP
    )
    """
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.close()
 
    mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(MQTT_CLIENT_ID)
    mqtt_client.username_pw_set(MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD)
    mqtt_client.user_data_set({'db_conn': db_conn})
 
    mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
    mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
 
    mqtt_client.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT)
    mqtt_client.loop_forever()
 
 
main()
```

La base de datos la crea, con los campos que yo quiero, pero no guarda los datos porque rompe al ejecutar el script de Python. Tanto la IP, como el usario/contraseña los he ocultado pero el fallo no está ahí. Me salta error en el comando cursor.execute y me dice que "name 'datos' is not defined". Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo y ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Cuando se ejecuta on_message Python se pone a buscar la variable datos dentro de la función. Como datos no está en la función, busca la variable fuera de la función. Como tampoco está fuera de la función Python se queja de que no la encontró. No hay más que decir, la solución es declarar dicha variable en alguno de los lados donde busca Python.

Comment: Que se supone que debería tener la variable datos?

Answer (score 1):

Tú recibes el *payload* desde MQTT; lo que te falta es extraer los campos que vienen dentro, lo que depende de como vengan formateados.

Dado que no sabemos el formato del *payload*, no puedo detallar el proceso de extracción.

También debes cambiar el formato del `execute`, ya que necesitas pasarle tantos valores como "?" tengas en el SQL.

```
def on_message(mqtt_client, user_data, message):
    payload = message.payload.decode('utf-8')

    db_conn = user_data['db_conn']
    sql = 'INSERT INTO datos_electricos (topic, tension, intensidad, potencia, factor, fecha) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()

    tension = ... # Extraer desde payload
    intensidad = ...
    potencia = ...
    factor = ...
    fecha = ...

    cursor.execute(sql, (message.topic, tension, intensidad, potencia, factor, fecha, int(time())))
    db_conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la variable datos (le llamé así por darle un nombre) es el buffer que envío desde el ESP32:
Esto es lo que leo en el suscriptor MQTT, y lo que pretendo guardar  en la base de datos]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZaV2.jpg

Comment: Hola, disculpa que no te mencionase @Candid Moe, es mi primer post en esta página y publiqué una respuesta que me convirtieron en comentario o algo así y no sé si puedes verla. El formato en que envío los datos es el siguiente:
StaticJsonDocument<256> meterData; 
  meterData["V1"] = voltageA;
  meterData["I1"] = currentCT1;
  //meterData["I2"] = currentCT2;
  //meterData["totI"] = totalCurrent;
  meterData["AP"] = activePower;
  meterData["PF"] = powerFactor;
  //meterData["f"] = freq;
  
  char JSONmessageBuffer[200];
  serializeJson(meterData,JSONmessageBuffer);

Comment: Simplifica tu vida. En lugar de enviar un JSON, envia simplemente un CSV con los cuatro valores. Al otro lado haces `split(',')` de la cadena para recuperar los valores **en el mismo orden** que los enviaste. Te evitas el uso de JSON en ambos lados.

Comment: ¿Sabes que existe MicroPython para ESP8266 y ESP32? Me ha funcionado de maravillas. http://micropython.org/